# Difference between File and Attachment in SalesForce

Tags: attachment, files

We have been using Notes and Attachment to store files related to the record. I also read about Files in salesforce.

How are Files different from Attachment? Are there any limitations or benefits of using Files instead of Attachments?

Are Files available for all editions of Salesforce?

Is it possible to link Files to particular records so they are visible as related list? I tried looking into the content version https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm but cant seem to find anything to relate to a record

Comment: you may want to see this https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_files_differences.htm

Comment: @Ratan Thanks that was a helpful document. Is it possible to relate the File to a particular record like we have parent id in Attachments

Comment: `ContentDocumentLink` is the place to look

Answer (score 2):

Files refer to salesforce content management system.you can create libraries for files and manage their access. Files tab is the place for these.Refer link below:

[https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_files_overview.htm&language=en]

Notes & Attachments are something specific to each record. you can control wether attachments are allowed on an object or not by a check box on object settings.Access to each record controls access to its attachments.

[https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=notes_fields.htm]

Each type comes with their own limits,refer to salesforce help for further details.

Comment: Thanks.. Is there a way to show that a particular file is related to an object record or group  of object records so they are visible on the related list of that record

Comment: As far as i know you can't use salesforce content management files for this.The best option for this would be chatter files if you are not happy with some limitations on attachments. Refer this link i found from googling:   https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2012/04/chatter-files-a-better-option-for-attaching-files-to-records.html