# What's the difference between "Files" and "Notes & Attachments" related Lists?

Tags: attachment, related-list, files, notes

What's the difference between "Files" and "Notes & Attachments" related Lists?

They seem to be a carbon copy of each other whenever I upload a file to one or the other.

Comment: You can take a look at [**this**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Attachments-are-not-returned-in-Lightning-Experience-search&language=en_US&type=1) and [**this**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_differences.htm&type=5) article to get more details on this topic.

Comment: I'm asking about the Related Lists though?

Answer (score -1):

This might be a duplicate question, but here are some resources:

- [Difference between File and Attachment in SalesForce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138230/difference-between-file-and-attachment-in-salesforce)
- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000231300&type=1